# C++ how to add "text abbreviation" in separate variables inside the strftime function?

Tags: c++, strftime

I am very new in c++. I want to setup variables in formatting date and time in strftime function in c++ how can I do it.

```
date = "%d";
year = "%Y";
month = "%m";

//inside the strftime function 

strftime(dateX, 80, " date + year + month ", timeinfo);
```

Comment: Where's the C++? Also, I cannot compile your example, because you haven't given the declaration or the definition of your variables

Comment: @KABoissonneault just because it could be compiled in something else than C++ does not mean it's not C++. It's also valid Java, and valid Python too...

Comment: @Quentin Why the C++ tag then? Also, it's not compilable C++, as proven by taking the code to any online compiler: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d28129e23078d16. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: This is my example I want %Y %m %d should be input by the user.


<pre><code>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <time.h> 

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  char buffer [80];

  time (&rawtime);
  timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

  strftime (buffer,80,"Now it's %Y-%m-%d.",timeinfo);
  puts (buffer);

  return 0;
}
</pre></code>

Comment: sorry I cannot convert my reply to code format